# Visual Studio can't find <algorithm> functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

So I have this probably silly problem : when I include the std algorithm library in my project, the compiler is OK with it. Though, it doesn't find any member function. For instance, I have this :

```
std::shift_left(F.begin(), F.begin() + 1, F.end());
```

in my code and I get the error message : 
`'shift_left' is not a member of std.
'shift_left' can't find identifier`

Though, I can perfectly use `<numeric>`. I have the same problem with all the functions of `<algorithm>`. 
Here I am working in the [min-devkit](https://github.com/Cycling74/min-devkit) so it might be this but I wanted to come here before going there.

Here are my includes :

```
#include "c74_min.h"

#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
```

I don't use

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Does your version of VS support C++20 algorithms?

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I activated C++20 on VS (which I didn't do) and it still does not work. I use VS 2019

Comment: C++20 is currently a *draft* standard, and any compiler/library support for any C++20 feature will - at best - be experimental, subject to change (as the draft standard changes before ratification in a manner that is influenced but not controlled by vendors), potentially incomplete, and not verified to be bug free.   By using C++20 features before the standard is ratified and compiler/library implementors have time to catch up YOU accept the risk that features you use may not work.

Comment: OK. So the answer to my question is : I can't use those functions with VS for now. I will use rotate instead. Its just less efficient I suppose. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Using Visual studio ``16.4.4`` with ``MSVC cl.exe`` version ``19.24.28316``, it has this function.